# Sphere inside of a sphere threejs physijs

Tags: javascript, 3d, physijs

I'm trying to make a sort of "lottery ball" simulator.

I'm having difficulty adding an object inside an object with physijis.

Physics work when I add the sphere to the scene, but when I add the child spheres to the main "lottery" sphere, it loses the physics.

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Thanks